# SQL Server - Bacpac import issue

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, database-administration, bacpac

I have a `.bacpac` file of database (created from azure). The database contains master key and certificate attached. Now, I have to import data into my local instance, I am using import-data tier feature but it gives error related to you have already database attached and create master key first. I didn't understand because I don't have that database in my local yet and `.bacpac` already has master key.

Why does it say: "create master key first" ?

This is the error screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the master key and the credential object from the bacpac prior to import it to the local SQL Server instance. **[Here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/exported-database-from-azure-sql-failed-to-be-imported-to-azure/ba-p/368871?wt.mc_id=DP-MVP-4015656)** you will find a script provided by Microsoft to remove the master key from the bacpac and you will find there other workarounds for this issue.

Comment: I tried powershell sript mentioned in above link. it produced patched bacpac file. and when import started, it started giving same error.

Comment: Please try to update SSMS to the latest version and import the bacpac to a SQL Server 2019 instance with the latest cumulative update applied.